SQL count function multiple parameters
SQL count function for multiple parameters, how are they defined when there are multiple parameters here? As follows, here is all the data in the table:
public ❯ select * from func_tbl;
+-------------------------+-------+-------+----+-----+-----+
| time                    | t0    | t1    | t2 | f0  | f1  |
+-------------------------+-------+-------+----+-----+-----+
| 1999-12-31T00:10:00.030 | tag11 | tag23 |    | 444 | 333 |
| 1999-12-31T00:00:10.015 | tag14 | tag24 |    | 444 | 111 |
| 1999-12-31T01:00:00.035 | tag14 | tag24 |    | 555 | 222 |
| 1999-12-31T00:00:00     | tag11 | tag21 |    | 111 | 444 |
| 1999-12-31T00:00:10.020 | tag14 | tag21 |    | 222 | 555 |
| 1999-12-31T00:00:00.005 | tag12 | tag22 |    | 222 | 444 |
| 1999-12-31T00:10:00.025 | tag11 | tag22 |    | 333 | 555 |
| 1999-12-31T00:00:00.010 | tag12 | tag23 |    | 333 | 222 |
+-------------------------+-------+-------+----+-----+-----+
Query took 0.008 seconds.

Next, I query count(t0,t1)
public ❯ select count(t0,t1) from func_tbl;
+--------------------------------+
| COUNT(func_tbl.t0,func_tbl.t1) |
+--------------------------------+
| 7                              |
+--------------------------------+
Query took 0.006 seconds.

Next, I query count(t0,t2)
public ❯ select count(t0,t2) from func_tbl;
+--------------------------------+
| COUNT(func_tbl.t0,func_tbl.t2) |
+--------------------------------+
| 0                              |
+--------------------------------+
Query took 0.006 seconds.

I checked the official documentation and found no relevant definitions
next I query the count(f0, null) , count(t0,null) and count(null):
public ❯ select count(f0,null) from func_tbl;
+-------------------------+
| COUNT(func_tbl.f0,NULL) |
+-------------------------+
| 8                       |
+-------------------------+
Query took 0.007 seconds.
public ❯ select count(null) from func_tbl;
+-------------+
| COUNT(NULL) |
+-------------+
| 0           |
+-------------+
Query took 0.005 seconds.
public ❯ select count(t0,null) from func_tbl;
+-------------------------+
| COUNT(func_tbl.t0,NULL) |
+-------------------------+
| 3                       |
+-------------------------+
Query took 0.007 seconds.

So what should be the definition of these functions by the count function in SQL?

You can't use count() on more than one column. The documentation is correct when it doesn't show it, because it is not possible to do so. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Where did you get the impression that you can do count(expression, expression)? did you just try and because it didn't produce an error you assumed it should be a valid syntax?

If you forget about trying to incorrectly use COUNT(), and instead post a question asking what it is you're trying to do instead, someone here can help you do it properly. You're not going to get anywhere just pounding away at the keyboard trying to use something that doesn't work the way you think it does.

@KenWhite Thank you both for the reminder.Here, I mainly want to ask, according to the definition in the document, I used the wrong syntax, why did I not get the expected error? If this operation is legal, what does this function mean when there are multiple parameters?

I have no idea why you didn't get an error. You should have, and every database I've ever used would have generated a syntax error for all the statements you've used. You should ask cnosdb support why theirs didn't.

You can use EXPLAIN <statement> to see what the query engine did.
